Error de ts en un componente vue cuando se usa un v-for y props
Tengo el siguiente template dentro de un componente (simplificado)
<grid-item
    v-for="item in GadgetStore.layout"
    :key="item.i"
    v-bind="gridItemProps"
    :x="item.x"
    :y="item.y"
    :w="item.w"
    :h="item.h"
    :i="item.i"
    :id="item.gadgetId"
    :minW="3"
    :minH="4"
>
    <ContenedorGadget
        :CardTitle="item.Titulo"
        :id="item.gadgetId"
        :MisDatos="item.Contenido"
        @cambiaTamaño="Cambio"
        :altura="item.h"
        :ancho="item.w"
        :noCerrar="props.noCerrar"
    />

Y en el componente tengo definida la prop como
const props = defineProps<{
    noCerrar: boolean
}>();

El problema es que TS piensa (o vue piensa) que la prop debería estar definida en layout (GadgetStore es un store), pero esa prop yo quiero que no venga de ahí.
Entonces, al hacer el build, se queja con el siguiente error:

Argument of type '{ layout: { x: number; y: number; w: number; h:
number; i: number; Titulo: string; gadgetId: string; Contenido: { id:
string; cargando: boolean; listacabeceras: { label: string; key:
string; }[]; datosbuscados: { ...; }[]; ... 5 more ...; tipografico:
number; }; }[]; ... 8 more ...; useCssTransforms: boolean; }' is not
assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<{}> & Omit<{ readonly
noCerrar: boolean; } & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps &
ComponentCustomProps & Readonly<...>, never> & Record<...>'.\n
Property 'noCerrar' is missing in type '{ layout: { x: number; y:
number; w: number; h: number; i: number; Titulo: string; gadgetId:
string; Contenido: { id: string; cargando: boolean; listacabeceras: {
label: string; key: string; }[]; datosbuscados: { ...; }[]; ... 5 more
...; tipografico: number; }; }[]; ... 8 more ...; useCssTransforms:
boolean; }' but required in type 'Omit<{ readonly noCerrar: boolean; }
& VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps &
Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_TypePropsToOption<{ noCerrar: boolean;
}>>>, never>'.",

Nótese que dice Property 'noCerrar' is missing in type '{ layout: etc.. cuando claramente no quiero definirla ahí adentro, porque no viene de esa clase, si no que es standard para todo el componente y viene como propiedad.
Podría traerla de la clase? tal vez si, pero no era la idea original. Hay alguna forma de aclararle a TS que eso esta bien porque viene de otro lado y no debería ir a buscarlo a la clase?

Intente desestructurando:
const { noCerrar } = defineProps<{ noCerrar: boolean }>(); 
También puede definir el valor por defecto para añadir directamente el prop al template:
withDefaults(defineProps<{noCerrar: boolean }>(), {noCerrar: false}); 
Template: :noCerrar="noCerrar"
Esto expone el prop localmente sin referencias a GadgetStore y typescript no infiere el tipo incorrecto.

con withDefaults anduvo sin problemas....
